# C - system function always returns -1

Tags: c

Every time I write even the simplest program in c using the system() function it returns -1.
For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%d", system("pause"));
    return 0;
}
```

I have used multiple compilers to make sure it doesn't work just with gcc.
It happens with every cmd command.
When I type commands in cmd they work fine.
The program just skips every system() function call.
P.S. I'm using windows 8.1 and the GNU compiler(gcc).

Does anyone have any idea what should I do?

Comment: How do you know it returns `-1`? Also, `"pause"` is not a standard command line command, it's specific to MS-DOS.

Comment: I print the value returned by the system() function.

Comment: You don't do that in the code you posted, also specify the environment where this happens, OS for example.

Comment: Are you executing it in a bash shell?

Comment: @iharob I am running the compiled exe file in the command prompt.

Comment: Perhaps you have some [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29) issue. Details are OS & system specific. Check your particular configuration. BTW, I suggest using Linux for learning C programming...

Comment: Seeing as it's Windows, perhaps the C library wanted to use `sh` (not `cmd`) and you didn't have it installed?

Answer (score 3):

When ever some library function gives error, try to check what exact error it is. Reading docs ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/277bwbdz.aspx), [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system), whatever) is a very good idea. C standard library functions generally set global `errno` variable, and there are functions to convert the code to string. So try something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int result = system("pause");
    // note: have to use temp variable for return value,
    // because function argument evaluation order is not defined in C
    printf("system return value %d errno %d = %s\n", result, errno, strerror(errno));
    // note, printf may set errno too, so it may have different value after above call
    return 0;
}
```

When I copy-paste above program to *foo.c*, start *"Qt 5.5 for Desktop (MinGW 4.9.2 32 bit)"* installed by Qt SDK, it works like this (a bit shortned/sanitized copypaste from the console window):

```
C:\Users\hyde\foo>dir
 Directory of C:\Users\hyde\foo
10.01.2016  10:25               443 foo.c

C:\Users\hyde\foo>mingw32-make foo
g++     foo.c   -o foo

C:\Users\hyde\foo>dir
 Directory of C:\Users\hyde\foo
10.01.2016  10:25               443 foo.c
10.01.2016  10:28            47 445 foo.exe

C:\Users\hyde\foo>foo
Press any key to continue . . .
system return value 0 errno 0 = No error

C:\Users\hyde\foo>
```

Comment: First of all: thanks for your answer! I tried your code, the program prints: -1 errno 22 = Invalid argument. i have tried understanding what does that mean, I have no idea...

Comment: @bobsfog I don't know either... Seems quite strange. You should update the question with what compiler you use, and perhaps compile options or executed compiler command line.

Comment: If you are using *gcc*, I assume you are using either MinGW or Cygwin. So I suppose `system()` will actually use `sh` to execute the command, not `cmd.exe`. So try these Unix shell commands: `ls` to see if you get directory listing, `read foo` to read from user, to achieve similar effect as `pause`.

Comment: @bobsfog As a side note, you shouldn't really be using `system` for... well, for almost anything. It's useful for quick&dirty things while learning, but you should only use it in "real" applications, if you really want to start another program. If you want to clear screen or wait for user to press a key, then use a library/write helper functions, which do these things with C standard library or OS specific library (WIN32 API for Windows console programs). Stack Overflow probably has questions with good answers about how to do these.

Comment: @bobsfog I added example output when I build and run the program. It does work with `pause`. You could also try installing the same environment I used, and see if it still does not work. If it doesn't, then it definitely is a system issue (system policy, virus scanner, funny things in PATH, whatever). If it does work, then it is issue with your build environment.

Answer (score 0):

This code (with "ls" rather then "pause") works fine in Ubuntu. I think it depends on your system policy.

Comment: Please explain *policy*.

Comment: I think he meant Operating System or something like that.

Comment: You misunderstood my problem. That command is recognized in windows, the problem doesn't depend on the command. Every command I type in the system() function doesn't work.

Comment: It works well on MS Windows 7 Enterprise. I do not have antivirus program. System policy means permission issue.

Comment: @LORDTEK Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: I had antivirus program. Then I got problem with compiling and running C application. Then I remove antivirus program. So you can uninstall antivirus program. I believe that will fix it. Or you can try to run program as administrator, but uninstalling antivirus is my favorite way...

Comment: @bobsfog fixed or not?

Comment: @LORDTEK No I don't know what to do. I don't have any antivirus and I cant find how to run cmd as an administrator... I am still looking for help

Answer (score 0):

Try right clicking on the exe and selecting one of he other compatibility modes.  Your program worked for me (Windows 7 Pro) so I might try that one first.

Comment: I agree with @hyde.  Post more information about your environment, compiler, compiler options...